# Why need the class Preference<T> be wrapped with object?

Tags: kotlin

The following Code A is from https://github.com/antoniolg/Kotlin-for-Android-Developers/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/antonioleiva/weatherapp/extensions/DelegatesExtensions.kt

I can use `private var zipCode: Long by DelegatesExt.preference(this, ZIP_CODE, DEFAULT_ZIP)` to invoke when I use Code A.

I don't understand why the author wrap class Preference(...) with object DelegatesExt

I think Code B is more simple, I can use `private val zipCode: Long by Preference(this, ZIP_CODE, DEFAULT_ZIP)` to invoke when I use Code B

Why need the class Preference be wrapped with object ?

**Code A**

```
object DelegatesExt {
    fun <T> notNullSingleValue() = NotNullSingleValueVar<T>()
    fun <T> preference(context: Context, name: String,
            default: T) = Preference(context, name, default)
}

class NotNullSingleValueVar<T> {

    private var value: T? = null

    operator fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): T =
            value ?: throw IllegalStateException("${property.name} not initialized")

    operator fun setValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>, value: T) {
        this.value = if (this.value == null) value
        else throw IllegalStateException("${property.name} already initialized")
    }
}

class Preference<T>(private val context: Context, private val name: String,
        private val default: T) {

    private val prefs: SharedPreferences by lazy {
        context.getSharedPreferences("default", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    }

    operator fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): T = findPreference(name, default)

    operator fun setValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>, value: T) {
        putPreference(name, value)
    }

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    private fun findPreference(name: String, default: T): T = with(prefs) {
        val res: Any = when (default) {
            is Long -> getLong(name, default)
            is String -> getString(name, default)
            is Int -> getInt(name, default)
            is Boolean -> getBoolean(name, default)
            is Float -> getFloat(name, default)
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("This type can be saved into Preferences")
        }

        res as T
    }

    @SuppressLint("CommitPrefEdits")
    private fun putPreference(name: String, value: T) = with(prefs.edit()) {
        when (value) {
            is Long -> putLong(name, value)
            is String -> putString(name, value)
            is Int -> putInt(name, value)
            is Boolean -> putBoolean(name, value)
            is Float -> putFloat(name, value)
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("This type can't be saved into Preferences")
        }.apply()
    }
}
```

**Code B**

```
class NotNullSingleValueVar<T> {

    private var value: T? = null

    operator fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): T =
            value ?: throw IllegalStateException("${property.name} not initialized")

    operator fun setValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>, value: T) {
        this.value = if (this.value == null) value
        else throw IllegalStateException("${property.name} already initialized")
    }
}

class Preference<T>(private val context: Context, private val name: String,
        private val default: T) {

    private val prefs: SharedPreferences by lazy {
        context.getSharedPreferences("default", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    }

    operator fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): T = findPreference(name, default)

    operator fun setValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>, value: T) {
        putPreference(name, value)
    }

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    private fun findPreference(name: String, default: T): T = with(prefs) {
        val res: Any = when (default) {
            is Long -> getLong(name, default)
            is String -> getString(name, default)
            is Int -> getInt(name, default)
            is Boolean -> getBoolean(name, default)
            is Float -> getFloat(name, default)
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("This type can be saved into Preferences")
        }

        res as T
    }

    @SuppressLint("CommitPrefEdits")
    private fun putPreference(name: String, value: T) = with(prefs.edit()) {
        when (value) {
            is Long -> putLong(name, value)
            is String -> putString(name, value)
            is Int -> putInt(name, value)
            is Boolean -> putBoolean(name, value)
            is Float -> putFloat(name, value)
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("This type can't be saved into Preferences")
        }.apply()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can use private var zipCode: Long by DelegatesExt.preference(this, ZIP_CODE, DEFAULT_ZIP) to invoke when I use Code A.
>
> I think Code B is more simple, I can use private val zipCode: Long by Preference(this, ZIP_CODE, DEFAULT_ZIP) to invoke when I use Code B

In the first case you can also import `DelegatesExt.*` or `DelegatesExt.preference` instead of `DelegatesExt` and write `by preference`.

> Why need the class Preference be wrapped with object ?

It doesn't *need* to be (and I wouldn't do it), that's just the author's preference.